# Inner Join and Select

Tags: sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server: Get Top 1 of Each Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/sql-server-get-top-1-of-each-group)

I have 2 tables in MS SQL. One of tblProducts and tblProductsImage.

And all products have min. 2 pictures. But I want to show only first image, every product.

What can I do this INNER JOIN and SELECT command.

Comment: How should the image be selected?  Randomly?  Most Recent?  Best Looking?  Also, please include the data available to make that decision.  *[And what version of SQL Server?]*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use apply you can use query like this, but it's ordered by id

```
select *
from tblProducts as P
    outer apply
    (
        select top 1 T.Image from tblProductsImage as T
        where T.ProductId = P.Id
        order by T.Id
    ) as PI
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
 SELECT * 
FROM   TBLPRODUCTS T1 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT *, 
                          Row_number() 
                            OVER ( 
                              PARTITION BY PRODUCT_ID 
                              ORDER BY X) RN 
                   FROM   TBLPRODUCTSIMAGE)T2 
               ON T1.PRODUCT_ID = T2.PRODUCT_ID 
WHERE  T2.RN = 1
```

Comment: +1 : But just to note...  To simplify this, remove one level of sub-query by moving the `T.RN = 1` to the outermost query *(in either the WHERE clause or the JOIN)*, and/or use a Common Table Expression instead of a sub-query.